# Django django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Hi I am trying to see if a user exists users in a ManyToMany relationship between my models.

I have two models:

1. A Course model
2. A Profile model

My course model is:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    course_content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course_likes = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='course_likes')
```

and my user models I have this field:

```
courses = models.ManyToManyField('home.Course',related_name='profiles')
```

in my course model, I have a method that filters courses based on the course regardless of the course description and checks to see if user exists:

```
   def is_liked(self,user):    
     Course.course_likes.through.objects.filter(course_code=self.course_code,
     profiles__id=user.id).exists()
```

and I am also trying to add a user to likes by:

```
Course.objects.get(course_code=code).course_likes.add(request.user)
```

Which I believe is also incorrect(Haven't tested yet since the first step is to check if user already exists)

Now when I test the method for checking if the user exists I get an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'course_code' into field. Choices are: course, course_id, id, profile, profile_id
```

I am using a template tag execute the method using:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def check_is_liked(context):
    request = context['request']
    course = context['course']
    return course.is_liked(request.user)
```

Which I believe is working properly as the error is related to my models function.

In my template I use (I have tested the course object is being sent correctly):

```
{% with course=course %}
    {% check_is_liked as liked %}
{% endwith %}
```

So basically my intentions are:

1. Add user to course_likes field of courses with same code at once
2. Check if courses with same course code have a user in their course_likes field

Comment: In your error it is `Course.likes.filter` whereas in the one above it is `Course.course_likes.model.objects.filter`. Perhaps something is not fully updated?

Comment: mope I migrated my database again same error I have fixed it in the question to prevent any misinformation

Comment: but the `.model.objects` part seems to be "gone".

Comment: No I  still used the same query but now I am getting a new error

Comment: sorry I found out there is a typo, it is `Course.course_likes.through.objects.` (so `.through` instead of `.model`).

Comment: Thanks to that error disappeared I am getting a new error now I have updated the question

Comment: I don't see a new error?

Comment: ah, in the `.filter(..)` it should be `.filter(course__course_code=..., ...)`, so not `course_code`, but `course__course_code`.

Comment: BRILLIANT! So I believe I have to apply the same concept when getting the like count will be  `Course.course_likes.through.objects.filter(course__course_code=self.course_code).count()`?

Comment: yes indeed, that's correct :)